# Python best way to create new dictionary looping through a list of dictionaries which contain lists

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, ldap

i have a PHP background and am fairly new to python, I am creating a helper class which is used to return some ldap results from an ldap server.

The standard result from pythons ldap library: ldap.search_s() is a list of tuples with dictionaries inside with lists inside ie:

```
[('uid', {'cn': ['cnvalue']}), ('uid2', {'cn': ['cnvalue2']})]
```

I would like to convert this into a simple list of dictionaries or in php talk an array of associative arrays.

For the life of me I cannot figure out how to do this.

This is how I have attempted it:

```
output = []        
for i, result in enumerate(results):            
    d = {
        'firstname': result[1].['givenName'][1],
        'phone': result[1].['telephoneNumber'][1]
    }
    output.append(d)
return output
```

If telephoneNumber does not exist for an entry in ldap the python library does not populate that key, so some times I was running into invalid key exceptions, therefore I modified to the below.

```
output = []        
for i, result in enumerate(results):            
    d = {
        'firstname': result[1].get('givenName', '')[1],
        'phone': result[1].get('telephoneNumber' ,'')[1]
    }
    output.append(d)
return output
```

Even so if a telephoneNumber does not exist then neither does the list entry [1], and so now I am running into "out of range" errors.

Help.

Thanks all.

Comment: note that lists starts from `0`, not from `1`

Comment: how givenName coressponds to `cn` and `cnvalue`?

Comment: It would be a good idea to post some data with names and phone numbers in the format you will be working with.  It is not clear how your list of tuples with dictionaries inside relates to your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
result[1].get('givenName', '')
```

This will return either a list (if `'givenName'` is a key in the dictionary whose value is a list) or an empty string (if `'givenName'` is not a key).

You will then apply `[1]` to the result. Presumably you mean `[0]`, but even so an empty string has length 0. You can't look up either index 0 or index 1 in it.

You could instead do:

```
result[1].get('givenName', [''])[0]
```

*Now* in the case where the key is missing you have a list containing an empty string. Therefore applying `[0]` to it gives you an empty string.

One alternative (which doesn't deal with an empty list, but I don't know whether or not that ever occurs in the data you're handling):

```
def getfirst(attrs, key):
    list_or_none = attrs.get(key)
    return '' if list_or_none is None else list_or_none[0]
```

Then:

```
d = {
    'firstname': getfirst(result[1], 'givenName'),
}
```

Btw, you use `enumerate` but then never actually mention `i`. So you could just as well write `for result in results:`

Comment: @alko: it's a dictionary. The placeholder for it in the example is `{'cn': ['cnvalue']}`, but the questioner is looking up `givenName` and `telephoneNumber` instead of `cn`. So I presume `cn` is intended either as an example of or a placeholder for the actual keys that may or may not be present in a given LDAP record.

Comment: http://www.python-ldap.org/doc/html/ldap.html says, "Each result tuple is of the form (dn, attrs), where dn is a string containing the DN (distinguished name) of the entry, and attrs is a dictionary containing the attributes associated with the entry. The keys of attrs are strings, and the associated values are lists of strings."

Comment: ZOMG! Steve thats was such a fast reply and exactly what I was looking for.

Thanks!